# How to upload a file to a website using shell/java

Tags: java, upload

I've to upload a file into a website after logging into it and perform few commands which need to be automated. Here are the step details of the website.

1. www.example.com>..
2. Entering Username, password..
3. Click on 'upload' button..
4. wait for 5 mins/until the processed file appears..
5. download the processed files.

So, Please help me with example. How to perform the above tasks with JAVA/Shell/any other scripts.

Comment: Can you show us something that you've tried already, and explain why it does not work? Please see what's considered [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you want to do this in Java, URLConnection is a good starting point (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

Comment: Previously I was using Jmeter which was developed by somebody and it stopped working. So, I want to find another way to do it. Btw, now I'm doing all these things manually for about 20 files. Since, I'm a fresher I dont have Idea to automate this. That's why asked for a related example which might help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use pyton script for the same as shown :
The below script is written by me to login to facebook which use cookies as well 
    import http.cookiejar
    import urllib

```
url = 'https://site.com/login.php'
values = {'email' : 'john@example.com',
  'pass' : 'mypassword' }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
cookies =  http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))

binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
response = opener.open(url, binary_data)
the_page = response.read()
http_headers = response.info()
```

Here the e-mail and pass are the inputs which you can get from the website .

Note : Not all website allows you to login like this .

Now refer to python docs for upload/dowload . One of it is http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_file_upload